# How to deal with non-feedback for assignment of applied job?

Tags: job-search

It's clearly my first question in here and I have a situation about a job that I've applied and talked with the CTO. I guess it's a position that huge apply count and I've sent my assignment for in time and with a very clear solution. It has a part with a database in real-time that living in Firebase Database and I've learnt that the company have hired a guy, but I learned it from Linkedin, they aren't personally mailed to me. So I'd spent 2-3 days to complete, I effort for the task and I've looked at the Firebase, so there is no query exists in the DB, they even not looking at the code. So I am little bit upset not for hire, I believe my code is running well but the team did not even check my submission. And furthermore, there is no e-mail and notification for not hired information for me. I respect myself and the processes that I've been in so I had some feeling like embarrassed but I've mailed to CTO, not get a reply back but I was thinking that there must be an even check the code and assignment.

So is this situation normal? and happens frequently? How to deal with this situation. Thanks for all replies.

Comment: I find more often then not potential employers expect the utmost level of professionalism from a prospective hire, but rarely give it in return. I have had more companies drop my application without a word than ones who have even said, "We are not moving forward..." There isn't really anything you can do...which is why I wrote this as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Yes, this is quite frequent and b/c of that it is "normal". You have an interview with the company, think you have nailed it and then you do not hear from them (It is really funny when they sometimes contact you in a few months/years and ask if you are still open/looking for a change and would like to interview with them). However such behavior now is backfiring at employers and candidates start to behave same way: https://business.linkedin.com/talent-solutions/blog/candidate-experience/2019/candidates-are-ghosting-new-employers-how-you-can-avoid-this

Comment: thanks for all your comments, I'll never wait any feedback again for the assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So is this situation normal? and happens frequently? How to deal with this situation.

While it is good interview etiquette to do so, unfortunately, an employer is not obligated to provide feedback on your take home assignment. There is also some gray area if you should be compensated for your time on the assignment or who technically owns the copyright should the employer chose to use your assignment in their application.

Personally I retract my application if a company has me do a take home assignment without compensation. There are plenty of other companies that do not give a take home assignment and a small subgroup of companies will pay you for a take home assignment.

Comment: Depends on the scope as well, a small project that could be done in a day or 2 and has a premise of demonstrating your expertise rather than doing the company's homework for a company I really like is tolerable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's very common for companies to "ghost" -- ignore -- the candidates they interview and decide not to hire.

It's rude, lazy, and counterproductive, but common.

One day you'll be a hiring manager. You can learn from this experience and be polite to your candidates.  It's a small world, and the way we each treat people matters.

Comment: thanks for your polite answer, I will be giving much more effort if I'll be a hiring manager or something because of self-respect.